# Django + Gunincorn - deploy and stay connected to the port?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, ubuntu-17.04

Correct me if I am wrong: I can use [gunicorn to deploy a django project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/), for instance I can deploy my app - helloapp in this way:

```
$ cd env
  $ . bin/activate
  (env) $ cd ..
  (env) $ pip install -r requirements.txt
  (env) root@localhost:/var/www/html/helloapp# gunicorn helloapp.wsgi:application
  [2017-05-18 22:22:38 +0000] [1779] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
  [2017-05-18 22:22:38 +0000] [1779] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (1779)
  [2017-05-18 22:22:38 +0000] [1779] [INFO] Using worker: sync
  [2017-05-18 22:22:38 +0000] [1783] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1783
```

So now my django site is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000.

But it will **not** be available anymore as soon as I **close/ exit** my terminal. So how can I have it stayed connected to the port 8000 even if I have closed my terminal?

Answer (score 0):

As with any long-running process, you need to run it as a service under some kind of manager. Since you're on Ubuntu, you probably want to use systemd; full instructions are in the [gunicorn deployment docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html#systemd). Note, you will also need to configure nginx as a reverse proxy in front of gunicorn.

Comment: how can I use Apache instead?

Comment: If you want to use Apache, you should use its mod_wsgi plugin rather than gunicorn. Once again, there is full documentation both [in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) and on [modwsgi's own site](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/).

Comment: for my own projects in the future i would use mod_wsgi plugin rather than gunicorn. I have this legacy django project that i am taking over which is using gunicorn.